# How to compare the (.properties) of two variables in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, shell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I'm trying to compare the *.properties* of two *variables* in **PowerShell**, but I can't figure out exactly how to do it.

I am using the **Get-AdUser** command to extract the *.objectguid* of two variables *(one for the userprincipalname and one for the samaccountname)*.

I have already made a logic like as below, but I can't understand how to compare these 2 *.properties* between the two *varaibles*.

- #### **Definition required**

**Input:**

1. **var1** = userprincipalname
2. **var2** = samaccountname

**Preamble:** *The user can choose to insert one of the two variables, or both.*

- #### **Desired condition:**

**1)** If var1 is not null:

1. Status success;
2. Do not check Var2;
3. If the user enters only var1 and it is null, status failed.

**2)** If var1 is null:

1. Check Var2 anyway;
2. If Var2 is null, Status failed.
3. If the user enters only var2 and it is not null, status success.

**3)** If var1 is not null and var 2 is not null:

1. check *(var1)* and *(var2)* if they correspond to the same User Mailbox.
   I'll use the *.objectguid* to make the comparison *(that is present in the action of success with Get-AzureAD)*.

- #### **Logic thought**

```
try
{
if ($var1 -and $var2) {
\# is case 3
\*\* My doubt.\*\*
} elseif ($var1) {
\# is case 1 (status = success)

     $A_user = Get-ADUser -filter {userprincipalname -eq $var1} -   Properties * -Credential $A_srvaccount_credential -Server $A_domain_controller

    $ObjectGUID = $A_user.objectguid

} elseif ($var2) {
\# is case 2 (status = success)

    $A_user = Get-ADUser -Identity $var2 -Properties * -Credential  $A_srvaccount_credential -Server $A_domain_controller

$ObjectGUID = $A_user.objectguid

} else {
\# fail (status = fail)
$response_status = $status_failed
}
}
catch
{
\# fail (status = fail)
$response_status = $status_failed
}
```

I don't understand how to make this compare in ***#is case 3*****.**

The *$ObjectGUID = $A_user.objectguid* is the value that interests me to compare of the two varriables (var1.objectguid & var2.objectguid).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `$var1.objectGuid -eq $var2.objectGuid` ? What is the end objective of your code?

Comment: Hi Santiago,
I need to make a comparison between the objectguid taken from var1 (userprincipalname) and the objectguid taken from var2 (samaccountname).

This is because a user can enter var1 or var2.

But at the same time it can also enter both values and in this case I have to make a comparison that it is the same user (user mailbox) entered as userprincipalname and samaccountname via the objectguid.

Comment: Right I get that part but why you want to take 2 inputs 1 or none?

Comment: We have a form where users can make a request to add a certain action. On this form there are two fields (var1 = userprincipalname) and (var2 = samaccountname) of a User Mailbox. The user can choose to insert (mandatory) a field. However, we have cases in which the user can choose both fields, in this case we must be sure that the user enters the same user, so that the userprincipalname and samaccountname belong to the same user, taking it through the objectguid.
 
For this reason I want to take these two inputs and compare that it is the same user via the objectguid.

Comment: Ahh now it makes sense, I'll post an answer later if nobody does but you should change the order of your comparisons to make it more straight forward

Comment: Thanks Santiago, I'm still new to programming & powershell. I await some input when possibile :).

Answer (score 0):

I think it make sense to have a [function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2) here since there are many different possibilities, using it would allow you to exit early when a condition is matches. I have added inline comments explaining each possible outcome.

Worth noting, both parameters, both parameters have a [`ValidateNotNullOrEmptyAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.validatenotnulloremptyattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0):

> Validates that the parameters's argument is not null, is not an empty string, and is not an empty collection.

This is necessary because allowing an empty string as input and using them in the filter would make the `Get-ADUser` call throw an error which we want to avoid. Ideally, since this is a GUI Application, you should add logic in your event handler to not allow empty strings or null.

```
function Test-User {
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $UserPrincipalName,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $SamAccountName
    )

    end {
        # Check if there is a bound parameter
        if(-not $PSBoundParameters.Keys.Count) {
            # if not, exit here
            return 'failed, there is no input'
        }

        $params = @{
            Credential = $A_srvaccount_credential
            Server     = $A_domain_controller
        }

        $result = @{ }
        # if `-SamAccountName` is bound
        if($SamAccountName) {
            $params['LDAPFilter'] = "(samAccountName=$SamAccountName)"
            $result['WithSam'] = Get-ADUser @params
        }

        # if `-UserPrincipalName` is bound
        if($UserPrincipalName) {
            $params['LDAPFilter'] = "(UserPrincipalName=$UserPrincipalName)"
            $result['WithUPN'] = Get-ADUser @params
        }

        # if the `$result` hash doesnt have any Key it means the query didn't
        # find any user in AD matching those condition so exit early here
        if(-not $result.Keys.Count) {
            return 'nothing found'
        }
        # if we only got one result in the `$result` hash
        # this means only 1 parameter was bound (`-SamAccountName` or `-UserPrincipalName`)
        # so we can exit here outputing the AD User
        if($result.Values.Count -eq 1) {
            return $result.Values
        }

        # if we're here we can assume both parameter were called, now we need to check
        # if both Objects are the same so
        if($result['WithSam'].ObjectGuid -eq $result['WithUPN'].ObjectGuid) {
            # here is for both Objects are the same, apply your logic here
            # and exit early with `return`
            return 'both users are the same!'
        }

        # last check, here we assume both users are NOT the same
        'users are not the same!'
    }
}
```